# Twitter Bootstrap Modal within Modal?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Is it possible to open a modal within another modal with twitter bootstrap?

I created a modal and put a link to a second modal and the definition for a second modal within the first modal body. When I clicked the link the second modal opened on top of the first modal.

I want the second modal to open as if the first modal was the entire window. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery's method `html()` to replace `innerHtml` of your first modal by the text.

Here is a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreT/KckM9/4/) where you only change the modal window's body.

Here is [another JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreT/KckM9/5/) where you change all modal's content.